# Symfony - awkward Password Length violation on partial User entity update through a form containing no password field

Tags: symfony, validation, passwords, assert

In Symfony 5.1 project I have a form that indents to partially update User entity records (some fields except of the password and email).
The form is generated with a FormBuilder class - a sub-class that extends UserType class, with "password" removed from the builder:

```
class UserProfileSubType extends UserType {
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    parent::buildForm($builder, $options);
    
    $builder->remove('email')
            ->remove('password');
}
```

Thanks to that the HTML form generated in Twig template does not contain "password" field.

But, the form actually **fails validation** due to "Password cannot be longer than 20 characters". Indeed I have this assertion in the User entity:

```
 * @Assert\Length(
 *      max = 20,
 *      maxMessage = "Password cannot be longer than {{ limit }} characters."
 * )
```

The point is that a hashed password is indeed longer then 20 chars. e.g.:
`$argon2id$v=19$m=65536,t=4,p=1$c21aeTNTbmsNL3dsaT3Y4RQ$E1B0bBI/SPjpIOItOFN2xs1d131YWTtDCw79n4fXJE`

When, for testing purposes, I modified the length assertion to `max = 100,` the problem is gone (worked around) as the hashed password length is 97 chars. Nevertheless, **why the form is validated against the password length at all?**

Is there any way to avoid the form validation error with lower value of password max length value?

Answer (score 1):

Default validation group means all entity validation constraints are validated. In your case you could define custom validation group where you define separate validation rules.

Take a look at the docs with registration example https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/groups.html

Comment: Thanks! That partially solved the issue. But created apparently another problem:
With these groups applied

`* @Assert\NotBlank(message= "Family Name cannot be blank", groups={"Default","profile_update"})`

`* @Assert\Regex(pattern="/^[\p{L}\-. ']*$/u", message= "Numbers and some special characters are not allowed.", groups={"Default","profile_update"})`

`  */`

`    private $familyName;`


NotBlank validation is not working any more (allows whitespaces entries into the form and throwing : _Expected argument of type "string", "null" given_)

Do you know why?

Comment: How do you specify validation against your validation group? You probably need to set in in your form or creating a form: https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/validation_groups.html

Comment: I did and it works. The mentioned problem is not related to this one - it is not a validation issue as tought before but it is thrown at $form->handleRequest($request) . It is described here:
[link](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/29061)

So this topic is closed - thanks again.

Comment: For clarity - this one I added into familyName field builder: `'empty_data' => '',`  and it solve the issue with the "_Expected argument of type "string", "null" given_" error